# How to cache forecast.io api data

Tags: jquery, api, magento, widget, weather

I'm using jquery with [forecast.io](http://forecast.io) to get weather data in the admin section of my magento website.

I would like to know how to cache the data for a certain amount of minutes, so i can reduce the amount of api data requests that are done. This way the new data is only requested after the cache time has run out.

```
<script>
            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

            $j(document).ready(function(){
                var apiKey = 'API KEY';
                //Go to forecast.io get your free API Key
                var curl = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/';
                var lati = 37.8267;
                var longi = -122.423;
                var data;
                $j.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: curl + apiKey +"/"+ lati +","+ longi +"?callback=?",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        //var json = $j.parseJSON(data);
                        console.log(data);
                        $j("#currentTemperature").append(Math.floor(data.currently.temperature));
                        $j("#currentTime").append(Date(data.currently.time));
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'clear-day') { $j("#clear-day").css("display", "block")};
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'clear-night') { $j("#clear-night").css("display", "block")};
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'rain') { $j("#rain").css("display", "block")};
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'snow') { $j("#snow").css("display", "block")};
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'sleet') { $j("#sleet").css("display", "block")};
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'wind') { $j("#wind").css("display", "block")};
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'fog') { $j("#fog").css("display", "block")};
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'cloudy') { $j("#cloudy").css("display", "block")};
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'partly-cloudy-day') { $j("#partly-cloudy-day").css("display", "block")};
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'partly-cloudy-night') { $j("#partly-cloudy-night").css("display", "block")};
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'hail') { $j(".currentIcon").css("display", "block")};
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'thunderstorm') { $j(".currentIcon").css("display", "block")};
                        if(data.currently.icon == 'tornado') { $j(".currentIcon").css("display", "block")};


                        $j("#humidity").append(data.currently.humidity);
                        $j("#currentWind").append(data.currently.windSpeed);
                        $j("#hourlySummary").append(data.hourly.summary);
                        $j("#currentSummary").append(data.currently.summary);
                        $j("#daily_summary").append(data.daily.summary);
                        $j("weekly").append(data.daily.data[0].apparentTemperatureMax);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("An error occurred");
                    }


                });
            });
        </script>
        <div class="weather-widget">
            <h4 class="wwl-title">Place</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <figure class="icons">
                    <canvas id="clear-day"  width="140" height="140" style="display: none;">
                    </canvas>

                    <canvas id="clear-night" width="140" height="140" style="display: none;">
                    </canvas>

                    <canvas id="partly-cloudy-day" width="140" height="140" style="display: none;">
                    </canvas>

                    <canvas id="partly-cloudy-night" width="140" height="140" style="display: none;">
                    </canvas>

                    <canvas id="cloudy" width="140" height="140" style="display: none;">
                    </canvas>

                    <canvas id="rain" width="140" height="140" style="display: none;">
                    </canvas>

                    <canvas id="sleet" width="140" height="140" style="display: none;">
                    </canvas>

                    <canvas id="snow" width="140" height="140" style="display: none;">
                    </canvas>

                    <canvas id="wind" width="140" height="140" style="display: none;">
                    </canvas>

                    <canvas id="fog" width="140" height="140" style="display: none;">
                    </canvas>

                </figure>
                <div class="temp-feed">
                    <h1 class="temp"><span id="currentTemperature"></span><i class=" wi wi-fahrenheit"></i></h1>
                    <div class="summdetail">
                        <small id="currentSummary"></small></br>
                        <span id="currentWind" class=" wi wi-strong-wind"></span><span>mph</span></br>
                        <span id="dayIcon"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div>
```

can anyone advise me on how to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just shove the existing data into an object, use that in your code, and set a timer  to go and get the data again every x seconds/minutes/etc?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say!!!... I'm technically still a novice. @CargoMeister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the data and assign it to variable:

```
 var weather_obj = {};
 weather.temp = data_return_from_api_call.temp;
```

Assign all the variables you want to store as members, as I've done above with temp. You use that obj everywhere in your code that needs the data.

On startup of the page, you start a timer.

```
 setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Where 'alert("Hello")' is, you write your code that retrieves the data. This sets up a timer that will run that function at set intervals, in the example every 3000 milliseconds, or 3 seconds. This updates the values in your object every how many seconds you think is appropriate. It will continue to run this timer for as long as the page is open on the desktop.